# Export WAR with complicated dependency

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, dependencies, war

I have let say three projects A, B and C. A has some user libraries that are exported in the class path. B uses this user libraries by its dependency on A. On the other hand C is web project and also uses the classes from the user libraries in A by dependency on B(B exports its dependency on A). I want to be able to export project C to war file that contains all necessary jars. I added in all projects their dependencies in the deployment assembly configuration, but this results in nested jars that can't be resolved by the application server(Tomcat in my case). How can I achieve flat libraries and what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: No, I am trying to do this only by the features of Eclipse(sorry for forgetting to mention this).

Comment: bummer this is sort of the whole point of maven. You could try Ant too if you want something possibly a little faster. When you have all these dependencies though it's best to have some help keeping track of them.

Comment: Today I came up with the following solution - add all project to the deployment assembly of project C and configure project A(the one with the user libraries) to also export the associated jars. What are the flaws of this solution? Can someone give me nice article about packaging Java Apps?